# Starting a Welcome Screen on first startup

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to display a few welcome screens on the first launch of my App. After which it will go to the login screen. But for efficiency, I need it to pop all the welcome screens off the 'stack' before launching the login screen, which is the reason behind this request.
My `main.dart` program loads into `preloader2.dart` which looks like this:

```
class PreLoad2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String myRoute;
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: FlatButton(
          child: Text('Press me!'),
          onPressed: () {
            if (loginCount == 0) {         // globally defined variable
              myRoute = '/welcome1';
            } else {
              myRoute = '/login';
            }
            ++loginCount;
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, myRoute);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It works perfectly well. But I have to click on the button.
I've tried both a stateless widget and a stateful one in preload2.

Can I write some code to replace the button so it just runs with no user input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get around, rather than answer my own question.
Inside my main.dart program I have added a new Welcome Widget.  What this does is to set up a new Navigator that in turn calls each of my welcome screens.  Each one in turn is pushed and then popped.  So it is not quite what I was after but it definitely does the trick and appears to be quite efficient.  My Welcome widget looks like this:

```
class Welcome extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Navigator(
      initialRoute: 'welcome1',
      onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
        WidgetBuilder builder;
        switch (settings.name) {
          case 'welcome1':
            builder = (BuildContext _) => Welcome1(
                  onWelcomeComplete: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                );
            break;
          case 'welcome2':
            builder = (BuildContext _) => Welcome2(
                  onWelcomeComplete: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                );
            break;
          case 'welcome3':
            builder = (BuildContext _) => Welcome3(
                  onWelcomeComplete: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                );
            break;
          case 'welcome4':
            // Assume ChooseCredentialsPage collects new credentials and then
            // invokes 'onSignupComplete()'.
            builder = (BuildContext _) => Welcome4(
                  onWelcomeComplete: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                );
            break;
          default:
            throw Exception('Invalid route: ${settings.name}');
        }
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: builder, settings: settings);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Each of Welcome2(), Welcome3() and Welcome4() are held in their own files and pass back a link to the next widget, either going forward or backwards through the chain.  The button code looks like this:

```
 onPressed: () {
        Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(routeName);
      },
```

Where the route name is 'welcome2', for example, which is then linked to by the switch statement that creates a new route to the required widget.

Once on the last welcome screen (or before if required) the 'finish' button calls the onWelcomeComplete function which simply pops the complete Navigator stack leaving the code to follow the default route ('/') which I set up in the MyApp widget taking me to my Login() widget in login.dart.  The code is:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(

      initialRoute: '/welcome',
      routes: {
        '/': (BuildContext context) => Login(),
        '/welcome': (BuildContext context) => Welcome(),
        ...
```

I hope this answer clearly explains what I have achieved and helps someone else.
Further information about the Flutter Navigator can be found here:

[Navigator Class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html)

Answer (score 1):

Just place the onPressed body into the build function before returning the Scaffold

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String myRoute;
    if (loginCount == 0)         // globally defined variable
        myRoute = '/welcome1';
    else
       myRoute = '/login';
    ++loginCount;
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, myRoute);
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: FlatButton(
          child: Text('Press me!'),
          onPressed: () {
           // Nothing Here
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mohamed.  This gives me an error when it runs now.  But I need to look a little further into the error to see what is happening.

Comment: Please show the stack trace when this error occurred.

Comment: I don't have any console output after the "Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk." message.  The emulator shows:
**setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build. This Overlay widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets. A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building... The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was:  Overlay - [...] The widget currently being built when the offending call was made was:  PreLoad2.**

Comment: The above may be a red herring! It actually seems to hang during the initial build - the console goes no further than **Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.**

Comment: Are you sure you have an emulator or a real device connected? Building app-debug.apk is a positive sign, but I doubt that apk is even loaded on a device. Check your device connections, and if the problem persisted try dragging and dropping the APK file directly on an Android Emulator.

Comment: Thanks @Mohamed for your help so far. I'm going to have to park this problem for now as time is short. What I shall do later in the week is try to write a very small App. that maybe makes the problem more visible.

Comment: I have created a gist: https://gist.github.com/pdqsoftware/29f4da12794462d6e7d4a53daefe535e which contains all of my files (using the button it all works fine) plus the modified preload.dart file.

The error is still as I mentioned above:

"I/flutter ( 5988): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 5988): The following assertion was thrown building PreloadScreen(dirty):
I/flutter ( 5988): setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build. ..."

Please can you help me again?